# How to take input int, double and String consecutive in Java language?

Tags: java

I want to solve this java problem. but i did not proper answer form my code. Below here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = sc.nextInt();
    double y = sc.nextDouble();
    String s = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Int: " + x);
    System.out.println("Double: " + y);
    System.out.println("String: " + s);
}
```

When I take input int, double and string variable, I can't proper answer. below this code's is input and output:

```
input: 
23
4434.2323

Give output: 
Int: 23
Double: 4434.2323
String:
```

At the input time, i can take int, double variable but i can't take string input. my code return int and double variable.
If can anybody help me, I will be benefited.

Comment: `next` only reads a token (up until a space, a _word_), use `nextLine` instead. And then be prepared for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: Do not use nextLine - it is common, but very bad advice (it breaks, see the first comment with 'but be prepared for'). No, the right fix is to set up your delimiter properly: call `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n")` on your scanner right after making it, forget about nextLine, and use next() to grab strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes because `sc.next()` goes till the end of the word (eg. space).

Use instead `sc.nextLine()`

Read the util.Scanner [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

But best practice would be to set a **delimiter** and keep using `sc.next()`.

```
String delimiter = " some_delimiter_here "; \\e.g. "\n"
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(delimiter);
```

Comment: Sorry, It didn't give proper Answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "It didn't give the proper answer"? I didn't give you an algorithm with a right or wrong answer. I suggested what you can use...

Comment: Input:
42
3.1415
Welcome to Java tutorials!

Output: 
String: Welcome to Java tutorials!
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42

Please give me a source code of java language which take input and give output same above. And  kindly see again my question.